# When using globals in a class it does not return module level globals instead it will just Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

When using the builtin `globals()` function it seems to do this: when I try to access a global value that I set to change from within the class (not a class global as it would be overwritten per initialization. The global I made is supposed to be kept and used no matter how many initializations of the class there are.

Like some example code:

```
somevalue = False

class SomeClass(object):
    """
    ...
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_global_value()

    def change_global_value(self):
        """
        Changes global module values that this class is in.
        """
        globals().somevalue = True  # Error. (line 14)
        self.__module__.globals().somevalue = True  # Error. (line 14, after some changes)
        somevalue = True  # Error as well. (line 14, after some more changes)
```

The Tracebacks that happen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
    globals().somevalue = True  # Error.
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'somevalue'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
    self.__module__.globals().somevalue = True  # Error.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'globals'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in change_global_value
    somevalue = True  # Error as well.
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'somevalue' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Note that since you have a class, a better approach would be to use a class level variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`globals()` returns a `dict` so you can assign a new value using `globals()['somevalue'] = 'newvalue'`:

```
somevalue = False

class SomeClass(object):
    """
    ...
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_global_value()

    def change_global_value(self):
        """
        Changes global module values that this class is in.
        """
        globals()['somevalue'] = True
```

The preferred form is just defining a variable as global:

```
somevalue = False

class SomeClass(object):
    """
    ...
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.change_global_value()

    def change_global_value(self):
        """
        Changes global module values that this class is in.
        """
        global somevalue
        somevalue = True
```

Note this is usually a bad practice in the general case and especially in classes.